# Python SPARQLWrapper freeze

Tags: python, sparqlwrapper

I developed some tests in python using SPARQLWrapper which generate some queries and execute these queries through SPARQLWrapper with an huge number of SPARQL endpoints.

Some of these queries are quite complex and they trigger the timeout of the endpoint.

the problem is that some endpoints does not trigger the timeout and the test freezes.

Is there a way to set a timeout in the SPARQLWrapper to bypass this issue of these endpoints that are poorly designed?

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue:

[Jira Issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MARMOTTA-267)

but it should be fixed short:

[Git issue](https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper/issues/19)